# Deploying a Remix.run monorepo on Vercel results in EISDIR error

Tags: npm, vercel, remix.run

I have a project with the following structure:

```
packages
app
| remix
  | app
  | package.json
  | ...
| ...
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

The `remix` project requires some dependencies from the `packages` folder, but this dependencies are installed globally in the root `package.json` file.

Currently on my machine the entire project works correctly, I simply have to run `npm i && npm run build:packages` and then just `npm run dev:remix` from the root of the project to correctly start the `remix` project:

```
❯ npm run dev:remix

> dev:remix
> cd app/remix && npm run dev


> dev
> remix dev

Loading environment variables from .env
 Building...
 Built in 5.5s
Waiting for app server (531dff8b)
> remix-serve api/index.js
Remix dev server ready
Remix App Server started at http://localhost:3000 (http://192.168.1.142:3000)
App server took 1s
```

The top root `dev:remix` script is simply an alias declared as `"dev:remix": "cd app/remix && npm run dev",`.

Now I need to deploy it on Vercel (I use terraform for this), the vercel project is configured with the followings:

```
framework: Remix
rootDirectory: app/remix
installCommand: cd ../.. && npm i
buildComand: cd ../.. && bash scripts/buildDeploy.sh
```

The `buildDeploy.sh` script is a simple script that build the packages with `build:packages` plus other things.

The build of the deploy is fine:

```
...

Building Remix app in production mode...
Built in 7.5s
```

But the `developmentCommand` (the default one, `remix dev`) results in the following error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, unlink '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev'
EISDIR: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, unlink '/vercel/path0/node_modules/@remix-run/dev'
```

It uses the `developmentCommand` because the deploy is not a production one, but a preview one.

What is wrong with this? How can I solve it?